# How to get Google Calendar Events only for a specific date not by date range

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-calendar-api

I am using Google Calendar API V3 to get google calendar events in PHP (Codeigniter). Now I want to fetch all events from specific date (Not by date range).

I tried with option 'timeMin' and pass date in RFC3339 timestamp but it returns wrong result.

My code is:

```
$optParams['syncToken'] = $next_sync_token;
$optParams['timeMin'] = date("c", strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'-3 days'));
$service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
```

Can any one please suggest me how to get event from specific date?

Comment: if you use `timeMax` may be your problem will solve

Comment: @Ayyappaamara yes...my answer already suggests that, see below.

Comment: i only given up vote boss.. again i would like to recommend him

Comment: @Ayyappaamara ah ok, thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can set the timeMax parameter to be 1 day higher (because it is an exclusive bound). Then you have an effective range of 1 day. Something like

```
$optParams['timeMin'] = date("c", strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'-3 days'));
$optParams['timeMax'] = date("c", strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'-2 days'));
```

See the available parameters at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

Comment: I am getting error if I add timeMin/timeMax parameters.

**"Sync token cannot be used with other request restrictions."**

Comment: @Sanjay It seems obvious that you can't request to do a paging and/or synchronisation of all your events, while simultaneously requesting to restrict the results to a specific time period. Choose which one you want to do and set your parameters accordingly. What you can and can't use with syncTokens is documented at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list . See also https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to add single events = true to your optParams in order to get timeMin to work, since that will treat all recurring events as single events.
so,

```
$optParams['singleEvents'] = true;
```