# Not sure why Google's calendar is returning the wrong events

Tags: date, google-calendar-api

I've been trying to make use of the Google Calendar API. It uses RFC3339 timestamps, for that matter I've tried to modify the provided example `2011-06-03T10:00:00-07:00`.

Right now, I'm trying to fetch the events between two dates I've modified manually (maybe there's the error?)

`timeMin: 2018-05-26T10:00:00-07:00`

`timeMax: 2018-06-03T10:00:00-07:00`

However, the events are not even within the date range, for example, this is the start date of one of the objects returned

```
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2018-04-30T18:00:00-04:00",
    "timeZone": "America/New_York"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2018-04-30T19:00:00-04:00",
    "timeZone": "America/New_York"
   },
```

Why is this happening? there are even some events from 2017.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49579733/3803805) useful. It's to do with how recurring events are handled by the API, which affects the `timeMin` and `timeMax` options.

Answer (score 0):

Your calendar is probably in a different timezone. Your current returning timestamp indicates -4:00 timezone, and you originally set the event in -7:00.
Modify it to look like this:

```
{
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2012-07-12T10:30:00.0z"
 },
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2012-07-12T09:30:00.0z"
 }
}
```

This will set Pacific Standart Time.

Comment: What 'z' are you referring to? There's no -06:00 neither in my dates nor the one provided by Google.

Comment: Provided example has -7.0:00 time zone. You didn't change that when you modified it. Now it looks like Google returns you time for -4:00 time zone.

Comment: No, I still have the same issue.